# Simple Spring Boot Microservice - Memory Usage Consumption over 300 MB

Tags: java, spring-boot, memory-management, out-of-memory, heap-memory

I have an environment with more than 50 microservices using Spring Boot (1.5.9 release) and openjdk: 11.0.4-jre, and I'm facing some memory issues that I'm not sure if it is really a problem or it is characteristic of Spring Boot applications

A simple microservice, with a REST operation and a soap integration backend, is set with the following parameters:
java: -Xmx128m
docker: --memory 500m

This application starts up with 305 MB

```
Total: reserved=1579MB, committed=305MB
-                 Java Heap (reserved=128MB, committed=128MB)
                            (mmap: reserved=128MB, committed=128MB)

-                     Class (reserved=1082MB, committed=65MB)
                            (classes #11972)
                           (  instance classes #11211, array classes #761)
                            (malloc=2MB #30794)
                            (mmap: reserved=1080MB, committed=64MB)
                            (  Metadata:   )
                            (    reserved=56MB, committed=56MB)
                            (    used=55MB)
                            (    free=1MB)
                            (    waste=0MB =0.00%)
                            (  Class space:)
                            (    reserved=1024MB, committed=8MB)
                            (    used=7MB)
                            (    free=0MB)
                           (    waste=0MB =0.00%)

-                    Thread (reserved=48MB, committed=3MB)
                            (thread #48)
                            (stack: reserved=48MB, committed=3MB)

-                      Code (reserved=244MB, committed=31MB)
                            (malloc=2MB #7957)
                            (mmap: reserved=242MB, committed=29MB)

-                        GC (reserved=54MB, committed=54MB)
                            (malloc=18MB #11546)
                            (mmap: reserved=37MB, committed=37MB)

-                  Internal (reserved=1MB, committed=1MB)
                            (malloc=1MB #2556)

-                    Symbol (reserved=15MB, committed=15MB)
                            (malloc=12MB #142322)
                            (arena=3MB #1)

-    Native Memory Tracking (reserved=3MB, committed=3MB)
                            (tracking overhead=3MB)

-               Arena Chunk (reserved=3MB, committed=3MB)
                            (malloc=3MB)
```

With Jmeter requesting 1000 in 60 seconds, the memory peak is 330 MB
With Jmeter requesting 2000 in 60 seconds, the memory peak is 400 MB
With Jmeter requesting 4000 in 60 seconds, the memory peak reaches 500 MB and crash with OutOfMemory

By limiting the number of threads to 80 (server.tomcat.max-threads) when Jmeter requests 4000, the memory peak is 452MB.

I also tried to create a simples spring boot application just with spring-boot starter dependency, but is also consumes 267M on startup.

Other microservices with 6 operations consumes 650 MB on startup.

The doubts I have are:

1. Does spring boot application consumes always at least
   250 MB of memory? Is it too much or it is ok in a cloud environtment has hundred of microservices consuming around 500 MB each?
2. How can I reduce the memory usage? Should I set some java arguments like Xss?List item

Comment: 250 MB is not spring boot requirement, it is Apache tomcat embedded web server. Try [another containers](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.2.5.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/howto.html#howto-embedded-web-servers) and repeat you tests. You can use [Undertow](http://zetcode.com/springboot/undertow/) instead of Tomcat.

Comment: Reduce the number of threads (each thread holds some memory, I thought the default was 1MB. Tomcat uses 200, so calculate that). Also check for memory leaks, as at some point things should get garbage collected, looks inyour case it doesn't correctly does a GC.

Comment: @VictorGubin thanks, I will try out other web server, but what I've researched so farthere are no much difference using tomcat or undertow in memory consumption.

Comment: @M.Deinum thanks, I've reduced the number of threads as I pointed out in the description

"By limiting the number of threads to 80 (server.tomcat.max-threads) when Jmeter requests 4000, the memory peak is 452MB."

I don't think that there are some memory leaks, by limiting the number of threads the memery keep stable in 452 MB.

But in a cloud environment, consumes ~500 MB for a microservice with one operation is too much.